# UITableView after inserting rows, update custom header's label

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I want to update my custom header's label after I insert a row:

```
self.billTableView.beginUpdates()
self.billTableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: self.data[row].count - 1, section: row)], with: .automatic)
self.billTableView.endUpdates()
```

In the `didEndEditingRowAt` delegate I get the header of the index path and change the label text. But the label doesn't get updated when I insert a row.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didEndEditingRowAt indexPath: IndexPath?) {

    let header = tableView.headerView(forSection: (indexPath?.section)!) as! TableSectionHeader
    header.lblTotal.text = "New Total"
}
```

How do I retrieve the section's header label and update it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you insert a row you need to pass a section to the index path so actually you got the section.

```
self.billTableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: self.data[row].count - 1, section: row)], with: .automatic)
let header = tableView.headerView(forSection: row) as! TableSectionHeader
header.lblTotal.text = "New Total"
```

Side-note: `begin- /endUpdates()` is not needed for a single insert operation.

Comment: Thanks, it worked! The code in my delegate wasn't even needed after all.